# Magento Using https:// for all links in source

Tags: php, nginx, .htaccess, html, magento

So today I was trying to install a fresh instance of Magento v1.7.0 on my vps which is running nginx. Once I uploaded the clean install to public_html I unzipped it and entered my ip to run the install i.e. xx.x.xxx.xxx:8089. Initially I got a "SSL connection error" in chrome, so I then tried http://xx.x.xxx.xxx:8089 this then worked and redirected me to the magento install page but I noticed the style was broken so I went to view the source and found that every link had https:// before it. Example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://xx.x.xxx.xxx:8089/skin/install/default/default/css/reset.css" type="text/css"   media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://xx.x.xxx.xxx:8089/skin/install/default/default/css/boxes.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://xx.x.xxx.xxx:8089/skin/install/default/default/css/clears.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
```

I then had a look around the default .htaccess file to see if there where any rewrites but didn't notice any.

My current Nginx config:

http://pastebin.com/CnsuwQ7B

**Note:** This is happening before I have even installed magento

Any ideas what could be causing this issue?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

This question belongs on the magento forums... (for best results). The contents of the magento distribution are beyond what most of us can help with.